# My suggested edit fixed a sign error, yet it was rejected twice.

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

These [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/684893) [edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/684910) fixed an error that the author had in his answer, yet in both cases they were rejected by two of the three reviewers.

I understand that it is not always appropriate to edit an old post due to it being bumped to the front page, but this is a critical math error and not just a style change.

I'm entirely sure that the math is accurate. Am I going about the editing process wrong?

Comment: Edited. (I won't call it a **critical** error though, as the argument are just the same no matter what the sign are).

Comment: The "suggested edit" queue is basically a game of chance. Sometimes you see garbage edits getting accepted in seconds, sometimes you see accurate edits rejected for no reason.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa. It's quite unfortunate that the validity of the reviews is so varied.